# How to setup params map in grails controller test

Tags: grails

I have an integration test.  The params that get past to the controller contain a list of multiple objects (phone #'s).  Each phone number has a type/number.  When I run the code I can capture what the gsp is sending to the controller in the params object as shown here:

[image]

How do I code that parameter map in an integration test?  Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked (below).  I'm trying to reproduce what the gsp form sends in controller.params before I call the action.

```
        def bindingMap = [alt1: 'Previous',
                'phones[0]': [type: 'H', number: '55555', deleted: 'false', id: '']]

        //controller.params
//        controller.params = map//[alt1 : 'Previous'
//                phones[0].type, 'H'
//                phones[0].number, '55555',
//                phones[0].deleted, 'false',
//                phones[0].id, ''
        //]
/*
        controller.params.phones[0]["type"] = 'H'
        controller.params.phones[0]["number"] = '12345'
        controller.params.phones[0]["deleted"] = 'false'
```

EDIT:

Figured it out:

```
    def bindingMap = [alt1: 'Previous',
            'phones[0].type': 'H',
            'phones[0].number': '55555',
            'phones[0].deleted': 'false',
            'phones[0].id': ''
    ]
    controller.params.putAll(bindingMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
controller.params.phones = [
    [type: 'H', number: '55555', deleted: 'false', id: ''],
    [type: 'A', number: '66666', deleted: 'false', id: '']
]
```